# Inserts using EF's RawSQL are not returning IDENTITY

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, rawsql

Given:

In the original post I was attempting to call `db.Database.ExecuteCommand`, since then I changed that to what you see here. (Which works).  Execute Command was always returning `0xfffff`.  SQLQuery returns the value of the last select statement or the rows inserted depending on how you code it up.

```
using (db=new MyEntites())
{
    var inserted = db.Database.SqlQuery<decimal>(query,parms}
}
```

Where last two lines in query are:

```sql
SET NOCOUNT OFF  
Select SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS newID
```

Comment: Does it work if your last line is simply `RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()`?

Comment: Put that in Query string or in .NET code?  I can't find reference to SCOPE_IDENTITY in .NET

Comment: See my answer, that should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your suggestions, Step 1 put something like this in the query string as last select:

```
Select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as TESTID;
```

Then use this EF form of SQLQuery, the type of decimal is what is returned for the select example above.

```
using (db=new MyEntites())
{
   var identity = db.Database.SqlQuery<decimal>(query,parms}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [`ExecuteSqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679456(v=vs.113).aspx) method, the return value is

> The result returned by the database after executing the command.

This means you need to `RETURN` the value in your procedure, not as a result set. So do this in your stored procedure as the last command:

```
RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: I'm not using Stored Procedures, rather writing direct queries.

Comment: SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable
    (field1,field2,field3)
    VALUES (@fields1,@field2,@field3);
    Select SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

Comment: If you're not using a stored procedure (and maybe if you are, memory fails me right now) the return value of `ExecuteSqlCommand` is the number of rows affected, not the result set. You may need to look at using `SqlQuery<>` instead.

Comment: This works in SQL directly    SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO dbo.Table 
(field)
VALUES     ('test');
Select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as TESTID;
SET NOCOUNT OFF;  But not in EF using the commandm I'll try the other method, but I had thought that the command method was required by Inserts